# Produce multiple SOAP web services in Spring

Tags: spring, web-services, soap

Here is a nice example on how to produce a SOAP web service in Spring:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

This example shows, how to obtian one endpoint and one service. How to obtain the same result with multiple services and endpoints?

Comment: Create multiple modules one module (spring app for each web service you need)

Comment: Hmm, in the end I need lots of endpoints and creating a module for each service seems like too much. Hope, there is a simpler way :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721604/how-to-define-separate-wsdl-for-different-services-in-a-same-spring-ws-project

Comment: How to achieve the same result without config file? I'm using Spring tags in java only.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on example from your [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/), all what you need to do is to add following methods to `WebServiceConfig` like:

```
@Bean(name = "webservice2")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition webservice2Wsdl11Definition(XsdSchema webservice2Schema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("webservice2Port");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("your namespace");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(webservice2Schema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean(name="webservice2Schema")
public XsdSchema webservice2Schema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("webservice2.xsd"));
}
```

And of course create

```
@Endpoint
public class Webservice2Endpoint
```

You can use as many webservices as you want in one module.

Comment: This doesn't work. Can't have same type of beans defined.

Comment: Add @Bean(name="webservice2Schema"). i 've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems, that both answers were correct. I used Mike Adamenkos answer with a little extra tags to get it working.

```
@Bean(name = "webservice2")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(@Qualifier("Name") XsdSchema webservice2Schema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("webservice2Port");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("your namespace");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(webservice2Schema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean(name = "Name2")
public XsdSchema webservice2Schema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("webservice2.xsd"));
}
```

So you need to add a name value for the `XsdSchema` methods so you can get the correct method in your `DefaultWsdl11Definition` with the `@Qualifier` tag. Hope this helps!

Comment: For me it works without specific tags... BUT you only talk about the wsdl generation (it's what the defaultWsdl11Definition does). 
Here I have a servlet mapping issue: Having two (or more) WebServices suppose differents mappings. This means different  MessageDispatcherServlet....But I can't make Spring deploy more than one servlet because MessageDispatcherServlet have all have the same name.